# Meaning of an english sentence

Tags: phrase-meaning

"The faunlet of a mother would designate the individual a portion of relative love toward both adult and child." 
I have no idea what the person who wrote this is trying to say.

Comment: Please state the author and title of the source.

Answer (score 2):

I Googled the text quoted. It is by a user of an Anime fan site. There is a great deal more in similar vein. The English is so atrociously bad that I am sure it is either a very low quality machine translation from some other language, or, equally likely, it is machine-produced nonsense (random text) intended to act as a placeholder in a forum post made for spam or other similar purpose. Or possibly as a joke.